# For a HTML page, is it possible to know the originating places?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, I have a Wordpress page and a reader might get to this page via Google search, Google adwords, Facebook ads, some other banners and so on.

Is it possible to add some code in the page so that I can get the information about where it is originated?

Comment: use google analytics

Comment: I know I can use Google Analytics but I am trying to do something that I can utilize the information when the page is loaded.

Comment: Analytics loads data with a script that is executed client side, which means _when the page is loaded_.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to know the code I can use to get the info to serve my purpose. Someone always answered it below. Please don't ask me to use Google Analytics because it's not what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer
It can be accessed via header from server side or client side with javascript:

```
console.log(document.referrer)
```

Many tools use this header to build up statistics, try googling `wordpress statistics`

Note: Your question proves very low or no researches at all, please try to search a bit more before posting.

Comment: it should be noted, this is something that can easily be spoofed.  and should not be used as security

Comment: I did do some research but I couldn't know the rightful terminologies to do the searches, so I couldn't find the answer I guess.

Comment: And your answer just helped me to write a bit of code to send the referer information via the form contained in the page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's okay, I just wanted to explain why you are behing down voted by the community :)

Comment: I saw the downvotes. I already had a feeling it's getting harder to ask question here if the question is not that specific or not that smart.

Comment: Since SO is getting tons of questions that are poorly written or that does not demonstrate researches, people tends to easily down voted. It's not a punishment or anything, just take it as a hint.